# Conditioning inputs and outputs when using virtual ground

Tags: power-supply, audio, synthesizer, virtual-ground, signal-conditioning

I am using a 120 VAC to 30 VDC single-sided supply to power a synthesizer that requires double ended power supplies, +/-15 V.

I am using a [TLE2426](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tle2426) rail splitter to create a virtual ground, then powering the voltage controlled oscillators (VCOs), low-frequency oscillators (LFOs), and all of the periphery op-amps with the +15 V, -15 V, and VGND that are generated by the TLE2426.

I want to ensure, however, that my output waveforms with respect to this virtual ground do not overload anything they are connected to and that any input waveforms will be compatible with my power system.

For the outputs, I am planning to use differential amplifiers whose output is with respect to my -15 V supply. Similarly, for the inputs I am planning to do the same but with respect to my ground. I just wanted to ensure that this is sound practice and seek any advice if you have any to offer.

Comment: A sink/source capability of \$20\:\text{mA}\$ isn't much. Are you sure that's all you need for the virtual ground?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use a few rail splitters on the board.